# Find all non-trivial triplets $(a,b,c)$ such that $ a+b^{d}\equiv0\pmod c $ for all $d>0$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

Let $a,b,c$ be co-prime integers $>2$ . Find all non-trivial triplets $(a,b,c)$ such that $ a+b^{d}\equiv0\pmod c $ for all $d>0$.

Comment: Why don't you just write $a+b^d$, for $d\gt 0$?

Comment: Does the triplet $(a,b,a+b^{n-2}$ count as trivial or nontrivial?

Comment: @IanMateus, you are right. I could have. But Most importantly, would that change anything? I don't think so.@paw88789, It's definitely trivial.

Answer (score 2):

If $a,b,c$ satisfy $a+b^d \equiv 0 \pmod{c}$ for all $d>0$, then $c$ divides $a+b^2$, $a+b$, and $b^2-b=b(b-1)$. If we assume $c$ and $b$ are coprime, this implies that $c$ divides $b-1$. If $c$ divides $b-1$ then $c$ divides $a+1$, since $c$ divides their sum.

Conversely, suppose that $a \equiv -1 \pmod{c}$ and $b \equiv 1 \pmod{c}$. Then $b^d \equiv 1 \pmod{c}$ for all $d>0$, and  $$a+b^d \equiv -1+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{c}.$$

Hence, for $a$, $b$, and $c$ pairwise coprime, we can conclude that $a+b^d \equiv 0 \pmod{c}$ for all $d>0$ if and only if $a \equiv -1\pmod{c}$ and $b \equiv 1\pmod{c}$.

Comment: To get nice spacing for $\pmod p$, use \pmod{c}; for example, compare $\mod p^k$, given by \mod p^k, with $\pmod{p^k}$, given by \pmod{p^k}.

Comment: @Morgan O, thanks for taking on this problem. I have not fully reviewed your approach but I just need to mention that since $a,b,c$ are supposedly co-prime integers, $c$ cannot divide either $a$ or $b$. Therefore,$a \equiv 0\pmod{p^k}$ and $b \equiv 0\pmod{p^k}$ are not possible solutions.

Comment: @Andy sorry about that, I guess I glossed over the "coprime" part when I read your question. I've edited my solution to include only the coprime case. As you can see, this makes the proof a lot simpler (the Chinese Remainder Theorem is no longer necessary).

Answer (score 1):

$a+b^1=a+b^2\mod c$

so $b^2-b$ is a multiple of $c$.

$b$ is coprime to $c$, so $b-1$ is a multiple of $c$.

$b\equiv 1\mod c,a\equiv-1\mod c$ gives all solutions.

Comment: Thanks Morgan and Michael but I beg to differ. I think the above illustrations give all the solutions for a particular $d$. I believe there are other solutions for $d=3$ for instance.

Comment: @Andy are we misunderstanding your question? I interpreted it to be the following: "find all coprime triplets $(a,b,c)$ so that for any choice of $d>0$, $a+b^d \equiv \pmod{c}$." That is, all triplets so that $a+b \equiv 0 \pmod c$, AND $a+b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod c$, AND $a+b^3 \equiv 0 \pmod c$, AND, ... so forth, for all $d>0$. Did you instead mean, "for each $d>0$, fine all coprime triplets $(a,b,c)$ so that $a+b^d \equiv 0 \pmod{c}$"? The difference here is that you first fix $d$, and then find solutions.

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant. I apologize if I misled you in any way.